# makeCopy Google Drive and Exception: Access denied: DriveApp. (line xxx, file "Code")

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script that makes a copy of a file for every row in a Google Sheet. It was working fine in February and early March 2020. It now (21/3/2020) fails with the error: Exception: Access denied: DriveApp. (line xxx, file "Code"). See comment in code below for where the code is failing.

```
//global variables to setup rows and columns to check for data
  var startrow = 5;
  var endrow = 66;  //edit this to be the last row of sheet1 with names or emails in
  var emailcol = 3;
  var idcol = 1;
  var namecol = 2;
  var isPresentCol = 4;

function makeFiles() {

  //Function to make a copy of a file for everyone in a list on a spreadsheet
  //Have the filenames include their names populated from the spreadsheet

  var activeSheet;
  var activeRange;

  //get the active range of teh active sheet
  activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  activeRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();

  //which file to copy
  filetocopy = activeSheet.getRange(2,2).getValue();
  activeSheet.getRange(2,3).setValue(filetocopy);
  var theFileReference = DriveApp.getFileById(filetocopy);
  var oldFileName = theFileReference.getName();

  //create file for each person - hardcoded rows and columns

  for (var i = startrow; i < endrow + 1; i++) {
    var currentValue = activeSheet.getRange(i, namecol).getValue();
    var newFileName = currentValue + ' - ' + oldFileName;   //change this line if you want to change the filename formatting
    theFileReference.makeCopy(newFileName);   //This is line xxx where the code fails

    //find the fileId of the new file
    var dupFileArray = [];
    var theNewFileReference = DriveApp.getFilesByName(newFileName);
    while(theNewFileReference.hasNext()){
      var file = theNewFileReference.next();
      dupFileArray.push(file.getId());
    };
    activeSheet.getRange(i, 1).setValue(dupFileArray);
  }
}
```

Appropriate scopes and authorisations have been granted to the script, verified in Project properties. Have Google changed the permissions required to use this method? What can I change to make this work. I trigger the script manually in the script editor only when needed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it failing on just one file or every file? Have you got access to the file and permission to make a copy of the file?

Comment: Yes, I own/created the original file and the folder it should be created in, so have full permissions. I have tried on my work and personal Google accounts with the same error. It fails on the first instance of running, so no new files are created.

Comment: Can you do the copy if you run the code outside the `for` loop?

Comment: @Jescanellas I tried moving the code outside the for loop and it still didn't work. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I made some tests but I cannot reproduce the issue. If you are already using the full Drive scope and you are the owner of the files, you shouldn't have any issue. If you are a G Suite user, I recommend you to head over their [support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en)

Comment: @Jescanellas Yes, it seems to work again now. It does give a new warning now that it didn't before. It says that the app hasn't been verified by Google and there is the option to bypass this and run it anyway. Maybe Google were changing things and broke things for a while? Thanks for looking at it and trying to help.